# ccavenue api integration with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ccavenue

I am quite new to codeigniter and i am developing an ecommerce application like flipkart using codeigniter and now i want to integrate ccavenue payment gateway to our website and i have referred many sites regarding this but i couldnt able to get proper solution.
Please someone help me out and provide me ccavenue api documentation.
 And i havent got codeigniter code for integrating ccavenue and i have gone through the below url
http://integrate-payment-gateway.blogspot.in/2012/01/ccavenue-payment-integration-php.html
to continue the integration of ccavenue.but i dont know how to parse php script to codeigniter.

Comment: It may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13859212/1725764

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you can get the documentation.

http://world.ccavenue.com/downloads/CCAVenueWorldIntegrationManual.pdf

And you can get the code from the ccavenue account. just ask for ccavenue account holder to send you the code zip folder which contains 3 languages code and you have to go with php folder.

Ask for the following

1. Integration Kit:
   Login to ccavenue account and click on the link to download the kit. you will find this within the "How to set up your ccavenue account?".
2. Working Key: 
   Go to settings and option links in top menu and click on Generate Working key link. And select activate option.
3. Merchant Id:
   You will see it in same page where working key is created.

After getting the code you just need to use that code in codeigniter's way.

You can also have a look on this code.

http://technoread.net/webdesign/payment-gateways/item/238-ccavenue-payment-integration-php

Comment: Both the links are broken. Can you please update the links?

Answer (score 2):

```
             **Here is your view file subscription.php**

                 <html>
                   <head>
                              <script>
                                 window.onload = function() {
                                 var d = new Date().getTime();
                                document.getElementById("tid").value = d;
                                     };
                              </script>
                     </head>
          <body>
        <form method="POST" name="customerData" action="<?php echo base_url('ws_user/ccavRequestHandler'); ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="tid" id="tid"  />
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="your merchent id"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="payment_option" value="OPTNBK">  
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="123654789"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_param1" value="your custom value"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_param2" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="INR"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="<?php  echo base_url('webservice/payDone');?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="<?php  echo base_url('webservice/cancelPayment');?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="billing_name" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->name;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="billing_address" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->AddressLine1 . ' '.  $addressData[0]->Addressline2;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="billing_city" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->city_name;?>"/>
               <input type="hidden" name="billing_state" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->state_name;?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="billing_zip" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->Zipcode;?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="billing_country" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->country_name;?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="billing_tel" value="<?php echo $addressData[0]->contact;?>"/>
       </form>
    <script language='javascript'>document.customerData.submit();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is your  CI FUNCTION

```
         public function ccavRequestHandler()
    {
        $this->load->view('ccavRequestHandler');
    }
```

Here is your file ccavRequestHandler.php

```
         <html>
              <body>
                <?php include('Crypto.php')?>
               <?php 
                   $merchant_data='';
                  $working_key='your working key';//Shared by CCAVENUES
                  $access_code='your access code';//Shared by CCAVENUES
                  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
                  {
                    $merchant_data.=$key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
                  }
                $encrypted_data=encrypt($merchant_data,$working_key); ?>
             <form method="post" name="redirect" action="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"> 
            <?php
            echo "<input type=hidden name=encRequest value=$encrypted_data>";
            echo "<input type=hidden name=access_code value=$access_code>";?>
          </form>
         <script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit()</script>
          </body>
         </html>
```

Here is your success URL

```
   public function payDone()
    {
                     $encResp=$_REQUEST['encResp'];
                     $working_key='YOURKEY';
                     $decryptValues=explode('&',$this->common->decrypt($encResp,$working_key));
                     $dataSize=sizeof($decryptValues);
                     /*CODE FOR GET YOUR VERIABLE WHEN REDIRECT ON YOUR URL */
                        for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
            {
                $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);

                if($information[0] == 'merchant_param1')
                {
                    $address = $information[1];
                }
                if($information[0] == 'merchant_param2')
                {
                   $userid = $information[1];

                }
                if($information[0] == 'order_status')
                {
                   $order_status = $information[1];

                }
            }
        /*CHECK PAYMENT IS SUCCESS OR FAIL */
           if($order_status == 'Success')
                                  {
         /* DO what ever you want after successful payment */                                                    Redirect('webservice/paymentSuccess');
                                  }
                                  else 
                                  {
                           /* do whatever you want after failure */
                                     redirect('webservice/paymentFail');
                                  }
    }
```

Comment: you can find **decrypt**  function  from crypto.php file

Comment: hi, can u please tell me where to get this crypto.php